# How to find records in MongoDB based on start and end date considering days

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How to return multiple objects from MongoDB using start, end date considering the days?

User Input -

```
start = "2022-09-08"
end   = "2022-09-17"
```

MongoDB Object

```
{
        "id": "63199ee82baa3643e58ed0f1",
        "start": "2022-09-08",
        "end": "2022-09-20",
        "startTime": "09:00",
        "endTime": "05:10",
        "timezone": "Europe/Rome",
        "days": [
            "Friday"
        ],
        "type": {
            "type": "remote",
            "label": "Video"
        },
        "interval": "15m",
        "store": "63199ee82baa3643e5887676"
    }
```

Expected Output - returning 2022-09-09 and 2022-09-16 as both lies in between start and end date also it's friday

```
    [{
        "id": "63199ee82baa3643e58ed0f1",
        "start": "2022-09-09",
        "end": "2022-09-09",
        "startTime": "09:00",
        "endTime": "05:10",
        "timezone": "Europe/Rome",
        "days": [
            "Friday"
        ],
        "type": {
            "type": "remote",
            "label": "Video"
        },
        "interval": "15m",
        "store": "63199ee82baa3643e5887676"
    },
    {
        "id": "63199ee82baa3643e58ed0f1",
        "start": "2022-09-16",
        "end": "2022-09-16",
        "startTime": "09:00",
        "endTime": "05:10",
        "timezone": "Europe/Rome",
        "days": [
            "Friday"
        ],
        "type": {
            "type": "remote",
            "label": "Video"
        },
        "interval": "15m",
        "store": "63199ee82baa3643e5887676"
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use mongodb aggregations, you should use **$match** aggregation to see the results between the **start** and **end** dates with specific **day** as follow:

```
[{
    $match: {
        start: {
            $gt: '2022-09-08'
        },
        end: {
            $lt: '2022-09-17'
        },
        days: {
            $exists: 'Friday'
        }
    }
}]
```

By the way you can use mongo compass to use aggregations, if you'd like to have a gui environment

Comment: I tried with this but the problem is for the object If I pass start as "2022-09-09" and end as "2022-09-16" it doesn't return any result, but I am expecting result as the date end date lies in between the record which we have in mongodb